# unable to use my jjil code

Tags: android, image, image-processing

Hi I watto work with jjil library. ı didnt use jiil  jar file I add source code.program doesnt have an error.But when I add push code eclipse add try catch blog.and then program running but ı cant see image at emulator.
my code is here

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
   int with=bmp.getWidth();
   int height=bmp.getHeight();
   RgbImage rgb=new RgbImage(with,height);
   bmp.getPixels(rgb.getData(), 0, with, 0, 0, with, height);       
   Sequence seq=new Sequence();
   seq.add(new Rgb3x3Average());  
   try {
     seq.push((RgbImage) rgb.clone());
   } catch (Throwable e) {            
     throw new IllegalStateException(e);                       
   }
   try {
     rgb=(RgbImage) seq.getFront();
   } catch (Throwable e) {            
     throw new IllegalStateException(e);       
   }
 }
 }
```

And my logcat error:

```
Log cat hatası : 08-09 07:57:14.061: W/ResourceType(63): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020030
```

But R.java not contains `0x7f020030`  code

Comment: check this is there in your drawable R.drawable.test. if its there then clean your project.

Comment: yes ı check and it is here.and clean but not working:(

Comment: if it necessery I use.but this code is very simple.but ıt doesnt work.I dont know where I had wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
    RgbImageAndroid.toRgbImage(bm)
```

This is full code

```
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star);
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();

    RgbImage jjImage = RgbImageAndroid.toRgbImage(bm);

    Sequence seq = new Sequence();
    seq.add(new Rgb3x3Average());

    RgbImage jjImageResult = null;
    try {
        seq.push(jjImage.clone());
        jjImageResult = (RgbImage) seq.getFront();
    } catch (Error e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int[] jjpixel = jjImageResult.getData();

    Bitmap bm2 = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);
    bm2.setPixels(jjpixel, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```